# Bias Correction for Hypothesis Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bias

I have some random data $X$ and an estimator $F(X)$ that estimates the magnitude of a certain effect corresponding to the underlying model. I am interested in testing whether the magnitude of the effect is significantly above zero for a certain dataset. The true distribution of $F(X)$ is likely very complicated, and thus permutation-testing is employed, constructing the empirical distribution of the effect magnitude for shuffled data, and testing the effect magnitude estimated from real data against that. The values of $F(X)$ for shuffled data are very small, that's good.

However, there is a catch. $F(X)$ is biased. Namely, there are some model parameters for which the true effect magnitude should be zero, but simulations of these models consistently produce data $X$ such that $F(X)$ reports a number slightly above zero, sufficient to be considered significant when tested against the shuffled distribution.

Due to lack of analytical estimator distribution, the bias has to be corrected for numerically. My only goal is to produce a hypothesis test that reduces the possible number of false positives at the expense of increasing false negatives.

The solution for adjusting for this bias that comes to my mind is to go over all possible model parameters for which the true effect magnitude is zero, find the one for which the estimator distribution is the highest, compute the estimator distribution for that parameter value, and then test the estimated effect magnitude of the real data against that distribution, as opposed to permutation-testing

**I would like to find the name of this approach and some literature on it**. The procedure is very similar to the [likelihood-ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test), except it is fully numeric.

Comment: Is there a value of F(X) that is low enough to be the equivalent to zero? It seems that you have already located a flaw in your model. If you truly believe this is a bias, you need not run awkwardly specified statistical tests to reconfirm the presence of bias.

Comment: @ToddD I already know there is a bias, I don't need to reconfirm it. I have real data. I want to test real data. I have to use $F(X)$ as an estimator, I have no choice. What I want to do is to minimize false positives in real data, where I don't know ground truth